# Firefox Addon Development: Setting the 'panel' to the bottom of the page

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to create a panel/frame that looks like the "History" panel that appears on the left of firefox when you punch in "Ctrl+H". I want my panel to be at the bottom.

I feel I must use [panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html) but there's no function that tells me how to set it to the bottom of the currently opened webpage.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `show()` method on a Panel object allows you to set an anchor for positioning the panel, `` `show(anchor) ``.  It requires an object in the browser DOM which you can get fairly easily.

You can use that to anchor the panel on any element in the browser.  It might be tricky to find the element you want to use for exact positioning, I just opted for the status bar since you wanted the panel at the bottom.

Here's the SDK code that will position a panel at the bottom (left) of the page:

```
var wuntils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390974/firefox-addon-development-setting-the-panel-to-the-bottom-of-the-page'
});

panel.show(wuntils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().document.getElementById("statusbar-display"));
```

Comment: It's not suggested use undocumented features like that one, because subject to change. The [show](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html#show) method doesn't take any argument "officially", the DOM anchor is used internally to bound it to a widget. In the close future, the first argument passed to `show` method, would be a totally different object – see https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/wiki/JEP-Panel-positioning

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not currently supported yet, but it will be soon. Here the proposal: https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/wiki/JEP-Panel-positioning where you can follow the discussion and the bugs. I already have a prototype that hope will land soon.